# Form in PHP: resend when refresh the page

Tags: php, forms, page-refresh

I've some trouble with PHP code using form when refesh the page.

I've tried to prepare a code sample to show the problem ...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="test" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
            City name: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"><br>
        </form>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $city = $_POST['city'];

            echo "The typed city is: ".$city;
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

All works fine but if you try to refresh the page (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in the browser ... ), a message comes out asking me confirm to resend and repeat the action and does not to clear the page

[image]

I've seen that there are some other question on this stuff, but I'm not able to adopt them ... any help / example?

**EDIT**

I've solved changing my original code in this way (starting form there ... https://www.canbike.org/information-technology/php-form-clear-data-on-refresh-or-back-button-press.html)

First file: NoRefreshForm.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['page1']=1;
?>

<html>
<body>
    <form name="test" action="NoRefreshCalculate.php" method="post">
        City name: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Second file: NoRefreshCalculate.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_SESSION['page1']))
        {
            #Do calculation here. Store in $_SESSION.
            $_SESSION['page2']="2";

            $_SESSION['city']=$_POST['city'];
            header('Location: NoRefreshResults.php');
    }
        else
        {
            header('Location: NoRefreshForm.php');

        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Third file: NoRefreshResults

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
  <form action="NoRefreshCalculate.php" method="post">
    City name: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>

    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['page2']))
        {
            # echo results
            if (isset($_SESSION['city'])) {
              echo "City name = ".$_SESSION['city'];
            }

            session_destroy();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['page1']=1;
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location: NoRefreshForm.php');
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In this way you can submit text, elaborate it and refresh the page without browser message on reload. I hope this helps someone with the same problem

Comment: For a simple search, it could be more easy to use the `get` method. It depends of the purpose. Otherwise, you could store the posted values (in session, by example) and reload the page using `header("Location: url")`.

Comment: some example on how to use `header("Location: url")`?

Comment: `header("Location: /url/to/page");exit;` Where `/url/to/page` could be your `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php